# How to render a textured polygon on top of another?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

Let's say i have 2 textured triangles.
I want to draw one triangle over the other one, such that the top one is basically laying on top of the second one.

Now technically they are on the same plane, but they do not share the same "space" (they do not intersect), though visually it is tough to tell at a certain distance.

Basically when these triangles are very close together (in parallel) i see texture "artifacts". I should ONLY see the triangle that is on top. But what im seeing is that the triangle in the background tends to "bleed" through.

Is there a way to alleviate this side effect, like increasing the depth precision or something? Maybe even increase the tessellation of the triangles?

*** Update ***

I am using vertex and index buffers. This is using OpenGL ES on iPhone.

I dont know if this picture will help or make things worse. But here it is. Two triangles very close to each other along the Z-axis (but not touching). (NOTE: the normal vector for these triangles are going straight towards you).
[image]

Comment: "technically they are on the same plane" vs "they do not intersect" - are the in the exact same plane or aren't they?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousands words.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg - a "picture" is such an overstatement in that case :D

Comment: I didn't expect that he would use MSPaint as his OpenGL implementation. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the Depth Buffer function to something more appropriate...

`glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS)` - Essentially disables depth testing

`glDepthFunc(GL_GEQUAL)` - Overwrites when greater OR equal

Comment: Or, you could just switch off depth testing. glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the depth precision up to 32 bits per pixel. However, if the 2 triangles are coplanar, that likely won't fix the problem. If they aren't coplanar (it's really hard to tell from your description what you're talking about), then increasing the depth precision might help. If you're using FBOs for your drawing, simply create the depth texture with 32-bits per component by using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32` for the internal format. There are several examples [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples). If you're not using FBOs, please describe how you create your context (also what OS you're on - Windows, OS X, Linux?).

Answer (score 0):

If they are too close (assuming they are parallel, not on the same plane), you will get precision errors (like banding artifacts=. Try adding some small offset to the top polygon using glPolygonOffsset: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml Check this simple tutorial: http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/polygonOffset.html

EDIT: Also try increasing precision as @user1118321 says.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called Z-Fighting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

Sadly depth buffers only have limited precision, so if the difference in depth of two polygons is smaller than the precision of the depth buffer, you can't predict which polygon will pass the depth test and be drawn.

As others have said, you can increase the precision of the depth buffer so that polygons have to be closer to each other before the z-fighting artifacts occur, or you can disable the depth test so you are ensured that polygons rendered wont be blocked by anything previously drawn.